# How to interpret model confidence set in R

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, forecasting

I want to compare 8 different forecast models to each other. Since I dont want to run into the $\alpha$-Inflation of multiple testing I heard about the model confidence set form Hansen.

I did this test in R but I've no idea how to Interpret the columns. I couldnt find an example that clearly shows how to interpret this tables.

```
  Superior Set Model created    :
        Rank_M       v_M  MCS_M Rank_R         v_R  MCS_R      Loss
model_2      7  1.841390 0.1544      5  3.15103236 0.0126 0.4410274
model_3      3 -1.121730 1.0000      3  1.08229686 0.8370 0.4325848
model_4      2 -4.495208 1.0000      2  0.01259591 1.0000 0.4295860
model_5      4  1.075427 0.5690      4  3.07628464 0.0174 0.4389964
model_6      6  1.809526 0.1656      7  3.24560851 0.0104 0.4394937
model_7      5  1.739335 0.1914      6  3.21338655 0.0110 0.4392409
model_8      1 -4.784771 1.0000      1 -0.01259591 1.0000 0.4295833
p-value :
[1] 0.1544
```